# Drupal Commerce API installation failed - TypeError: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: drupal, decoupling, drupal-commerce

I have installed [Drupal commerce](https://drupalcommerce.org/) on Druapl 8 site. I need to expose commerce features via an API. when I try to enable [Commerce API](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_api) module I am getting following error.

`TypeError: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, int given in strpos() (line 33 of /var/www/html/web/modules/contrib/commerce_api/src/ParamConverter/EntityUuidConverter.php)`

Answer (score 0):

I have updated `modules/contrib/commerce_api/src/ParamConverter/EntityUuidConverter.php`
file as follows.

`$name` to `strval($name)`

```
public function applies($definition, $name, Route $route) {
    return strpos(strval($name), 'commerce_') === 0;
}
```

Commerce API got enabled.